# A wrapper library for League Of Legends API

Tags: beginner, rust, api, wrapper

I'm a new Rustacean, decided to make a wrapper for the LeagueOfLegends API.

Focus is on simplicity, being able to make any API call with a simple function.

I have not finished all functions however it's currently in a working state, and the other function will be very similair.

### Code

**Lib.rs** - I've included this file as I'm new to Rust and may not be using the file properly

```
pub mod riot_api;
pub use riot_api::*;

pub mod api_structs {
    pub mod lol_api_key;
    pub mod lol_region;
    pub mod lol_account;
}

pub mod util {
    pub (crate) mod http_client;
    pub mod http_error;
}
```

**src/riot_api.rs** - This is the library main file, containing all public methods

```
use crate::api_structs::lol_api_key::LolApiKey;
use crate::api_structs::lol_account::LeagueAccount;
use crate::util::http_client::HttpClient;
use crate::util::http_error::HttpError;

pub struct RiotApi {
}

impl RiotApi {
    const SUMMONER_BY_NAME_URL: &'static str = "https://%region%.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/%name%?api_key=%apikey%";
    const GET_STATUS_URL : &'static str = "https://%region%.api.riotgames.com/lol/status/v3/shard-data?api_key=%apikey%";

    fn get_url_from_api_key(original_url : &str, lol_api_key : &LolApiKey) -> String {
        return original_url
            .replace("%region%", lol_api_key.region.get_code())
            .replace("%apikey%", &*lol_api_key.api_key);
    }

    fn get_url_from_api_key_with_name(original_url : &str, lol_api_key : &LolApiKey, name : String) -> String {
        return Self::get_url_from_api_key(original_url, lol_api_key)
            .replace("%name%", name.as_str());
    }

    pub fn get_status(lol_api_key : &LolApiKey) -> Result<String, HttpError> {
        let url : String = Self::get_url_from_api_key(RiotApi::GET_STATUS_URL, lol_api_key);

        return HttpClient::get(url);
    }

    pub fn get_summoner(summoner_name : String, lol_api_key : &LolApiKey) -> Result<LeagueAccount, HttpError> {
        let url : String = Self::get_url_from_api_key_with_name(RiotApi::SUMMONER_BY_NAME_URL, lol_api_key, summoner_name);

        let http_result = HttpClient::get(url);

        if http_result.is_ok() {
            let league_account : LeagueAccount = serde_json::from_str(&http_result.unwrap()).unwrap();

            return Ok(league_account);
        } else {
            return Err(http_result.unwrap_err());
        }
    }
}
```

**src/util/http_client.rs** - This is a wrapper class for an http library. It shouldn't be used outside this project

```
use reqwest;
use crate::util::http_error::HttpError;

pub struct HttpClient {
}

/**
 * Class to handle HTTP calls. Basically just a wrapper for an external HTTP client, to make management/changes easier
*/
impl HttpClient {
    pub fn get(url : String) -> Result<String, HttpError> {
        let http_result = Self::http_get_result(url);

        return match http_result {
            Ok(result) => {
                if result.status() == 200 {
                    Result::Ok(String::from(result.text().unwrap()))
                } else if result.status() == 401 {
                    Result::Err(HttpError{ error_message: String::from("Unauthorized access to application"),
                        http_response_code: Some(401) })
                } else if result.status() == 403 {
                    Result::Err(HttpError{ error_message: String::from("Forbidden access to application. Check if API key has expired"),
                        http_response_code: Some(403) })
                }else {
                    Result::Err(HttpError{ error_message: String::from("Error in http request"),
                        http_response_code: Some(result.status().as_u16()) })
                }
            },
            Err(error) => {
                Result::Err(HttpError { error_message: error.to_string(), http_response_code: None })
            }
        };
    }

    fn http_get_result(url : String) -> Result<reqwest::blocking::Response, reqwest::Error> {
        return reqwest::blocking::get(&url);
    }
}
```

**http_error.rs** - Used for http errors when making network class

```
#[derive(PartialEq)]
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct HttpError {
    pub error_message : String,
    pub http_response_code : Option<u16>
}

impl HttpError {
}
```

Comment: Use `pub(crate)` to make struct available for your lib only.

Comment: @outoftime Thanks, I updated it and realized 'http_error' needs to be public